# Local database in C# with stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a problem and I really need your help. Please help me as soon as you can. Here is my story. I create a local database in Visual Studio for my project. I mean I right click on my project and choose add and  add a service base database to my project with the name of `OCRDataBase`.

My first problem is this: I create this stored procedure in Server Explorer menu of Visual Studio for my database

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckDataBase]
    @Shape int ,
    @p1 int ,
    @p2 int ,
    @p3 int ,
    @p4 int ,
    @output nvarchar(10) out
as
Begin
    select 
        @output = [Character] 
    from 
        dbo.OCRTable 
    where 
        Style = @Shape 
        and Part1 = @p1 and Part2 = @p2 and Part3 = @p3 and Part4 = @p4;

    if(@output is null)
        select @output = '[Unknown]';
End
```

I have a table with 6 columns (`id, style, part1, part2, part3, part4`, character).

This stored procedure is supposed to return character and if there wasn’t any character to match the stored procedure condition it suppose to return  '[Unknown]';

I write this function in Visual Studio to get the value this this stored procedure return

```
static public string Check(int Shape, int p1, int p2, int p3, int p4)
{
            string FunctionOutput = "";

            try
            {
                Connection.Open();
                SqlCommand SqlCommands = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[CheckDataBase]", Connection);
                SqlCommands.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlCommands.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shape", Shape);
                SqlCommands.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", p1);
                SqlCommands.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", p2);
                SqlCommands.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", p3);
                SqlCommands.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", p4);

                SqlParameter OutputParameter = new SqlParameter();
                OutputParameter.ParameterName = "@output";
                OutputParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
                OutputParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                SqlCommands.Parameters.Add(OutputParameter);

                SqlCommands.ExecuteNonQuery();
                FunctionOutput = OutputParameter.Value.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(FunctionOutput);
            }
            catch (SqlException exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                Connection.Close();
            }
            return FunctionOutput;
}
```

But when `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` executes, this message shows up:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: String[5]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.

What should I do? Please help me.

My second question is how can I give relative address to that database so I can run my application from any folder and in any computer.

It is my database connection:

```
static private SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\Modem Project\PROJECT\OCR\OCR\OCRDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```

I try to write

```
..\..\OCRDataBase.mdf instead of  D:\Modem Project\PROJECT\OCR\OCR\OCRDataBase.mdf
```

But this was Visual Studio message:

> There is already a database with that name in this folder.

It seems Visual Studio want to replace it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you are only passing 5 params vs 7 why don't you look at the params again that you are passing..
`I have table with 5 rows (id,style,part1,part2,part3,part4, Character)` I am counting 7 params if this is not the case can you run this manually in sql server management studio and hard code the values to see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.size(v=vs.110).aspx),

> For output parameters with a variable length type (nvarchar, for
>   example), the size of the parameter defines the size of the buffer
>   holding the output parameter. The output parameter can be truncated to
>   a size specified with Size. For character types, the size specified
>   with Size is in characters.

In your case, you are trying to return `nvarchar` from your stored procedure, so try to set size like this,

```
SqlParameter OutputParameter = new SqlParameter();
OutputParameter.ParameterName = "@output";
OutputParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
OutputParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
OutputParameter.Size = 10;
SqlCommands.Parameters.Add(OutputParameter);
```

Comment: thaks a lot. it work perfectly.your my superhero. lol . can you help me with second question. how can i give relative address to my local database so i can run my program from any location.

Comment: @Mike please ask the question in `Stackoverflow.com`. I don't know about the relative address. :(

Comment: i find my second question answer. thanks a lot for your effort.